# Get CST date in linux shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, date, date-conversion

I am trying to get the current date in CST format in linux.

```
todaysDate=$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S);
echo 'todaysDate: '${todaysDate};
```

> Result: todaysDate: 2022-06-03-09:15:42

is giving me time in UTC. How can I get the time in CST instead, without changing the system time settings?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48101/how-can-i-have-date-output-the-time-from-a-different-timezone) on the Unix stack exchange. You basically prepend an environment variable that is only valid for the very command you're trying to issue:

```
$(TZ=<Your Timezone> date +%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S)
```

All available timezones are listed in `/usr/share/zoneinfo`.

Answer (score 0):

Set the environment variable `TZ` to `CST6CDT`.

```
todaysDate=$(TZ=CST6CDT date +%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S);
```